# Turning an Estimate into an Invoice with Quickbooks Online v3 API

Tags: quickbooks-online

Didn't see this asked anywhere so it is either super obvious or not possible..

Just curious if there was a way using QBOV3 API to turn an estimate into a Invoice.  In the QBO frontend there is a 'Copy to Invoice' button that will take the info and dump it into a newly formed Invoice.  I was curious if there was an API action that could do this or if I had to copy all of the information and create a new invoice and then back fill the LinkedTxn on the Estimate with the newly formed Invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API which will directly convert an estimate to an invoice.

But, as you said in the 2nd part, you can read estimate's data and then map that with the attributes of Invoice.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/estimate

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/invoice

Thanks

Comment: sadly that's what I thought...Thanks for the help!

Comment: Confirmed that's all I've found as well ... sure would be nice to just call the Estimate service and say "convert". But noooooo.